# Protocols and delegation in swift 3 not sending values between viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, swift

I have two viewcontrollers(`SignInViewcontroller.swift` and `ProfilePage.swift`)
I want to pass the string from `SignInViewcontroller` to `ProfilePage` `viewcontroller`.
I created a protocol in `SignInViewcontroller`.And I delegate the method in `ProfilePage` `controller`.When I send the string through protocols I didn't receive that string in `ProfilePage` `viewcontroller` Where I am wrong.please help me to solve.
Here is my code:

**SignInViewController.swift**

```
protocol sendTokenDelegate: class {
    func sendToken(login:String)
}
class SignInViewController: UIViewController  {
    weak var delegateToken:sendTokenDelegate?
    func loginAzure(email: String, password: String) {
        token = "abcdefgh"
        self.delegateToken?.sendToken(login: token)
    }
}
```

**ProfilePage.swift**

```
class ProfilePage: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, sendTokenDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let signInVC = SignInViewController()
        signInVC.delegateToken = self
    }
    func sendToken(login: String) {
        self.logInToken = login
        print("Login Token in Profile Page is \(login)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you going to SignInViewController to ProfilePage?

Comment: How and where do you present `SignInViewController `?

Comment: yes.I want to send string from SignInViewcontroller to ProfilePage

Comment: Where does `loginAzure(email: String, password: String) ` method get called?

Comment: After I sign In I will get the response . I don't want to present SignInViewController.Just I want to pass the string value  when ProfilePage loads I want to get the token string from SignInViewController through delegates.

Comment: when I click the button loginAzure will call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you need  object that will store token from SignInViewController, until ProfilePage is requesting it.

```
class TokenStorage {
    static let shared = TokenStorage()
    public var token: String = ""
}
```

then you receive token call:

```
TokenStorage.shared.token = receivedToken
```

and in ProfilePage request it:

```
print(TokenStorage.shared.token)
```

Comment: I am not using any segue.My need is I just want to pass the data from one viewcontroller to another viewcontroller using protocols and delegates.

Comment: In that case, you need <another> object that will store token from SignInViewController, until ProfilePage is requesting it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are coming from SignUpViewController to ProfilePageViewController, you can pass the string values upon navigation after getting the singIn token you want from your logingAzure() I assume:

1. If you navigate using segues -> self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signUpToProfile", sender: self)

   ```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       if segue.identifier == "signUpToProfile" {
          if let profileVC : ProfilePageViewController = 
           segue.destination as? ProfilePageViewController {
           profileVC.loginToken = token
          }
       }
   }
   ```
2. If you are using self.navigationController?.pushViewController

   ```
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Profile", bundle: Bundle.main)
   if let profileVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:
                "ProfilePageViewController") as? ProfilePageViewController {
       profileVC.loginToken = token
   }
   ```

**EDIT**

If you are not going to profilePage directly from SignUpViewController,
then just save the token in your Keychain OR UserDefaults.

Do this by creating a `SessionManager` singleton to handle tokens and other resources when logging in or signing up

Comment: I am not using segues and navigation controllers.I have a token string in SignInViewController.When I loads the ProfilePage viewcontroller I want to get that token values from SignInViewController.So how do I do that?I used Protocols and Delegates method to send and receive datas

Comment: the problem is that your ProfileViewController is not yet existing so there is nothing to catch the sent token. So in order to do that you may need to create a SessionManager (Singleton), so you can save the token for later use; save it to Keychain OR in your UserDefaults.

I added an edit section to answer

Comment: To catch the sent token from SignInViewController from ProfilePageViewController delegates won't work? SessionManager/UserDefaults is a good thing.But why delegates not working?

Comment: hmm. it's because upon running the application and going through the sign up page, only the SignUpViewController is in existence.

When you create the ProfilePageVC (didLoad), you need to set its delegate to that of SignUpViewController, but making a copy to trace that SignUpVC would be bad practice. delegates would work but it would make your code complicated.

Comment: The explanation given by @Ace Rivera is perfectly true.

Answer (score 0):

When you are going to NextVC that doesn't exist in the navigation controller then you have to bind data with the instance of the class when you are pushing just like that:

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "ProfilePage", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as! ProfilePage
vc. logInToken = "abcdefgh"
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

class ProfilePage: UIViewController {
   var logInToken = "" // you will receive the token in this variable.
}
```

In you case, it seems like `ProfilePage` doesn't exist.

**NOTE:- Delegate will use just opposite case when you want to pass the value from `ProfilePage` to SignInViewController.**

**OR**

If your all API wants the token so you can declare at the class level or save it to UserDefauls:

**1)**

```
var logInToken = "" // your variable visible the entire application classes
class ProfilePage: UIViewController {

}

func loginAzure(email: String, password: String) {
    logInToken = "abcdefgh" //Just assign and use it
}
```

**2)**

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("aasdfa", forKey: "token")
let token = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "token"
```

> Also, you are doing the bad coding you have to understand the OOP's
>
> ```
> let signInVC = SignInViewController()
> signInVC.delegateToken = self
> ```
>
> This will reperensent the seprate instance in the memory and every
>   object has its own properties and behavior.

Comment: I am not directly going from  SignInViewController to ProfilePage. In SignInViewController I get the JSON Token. When I load the ProfilePage I want to get that token.

Comment: Are you using segua?

Comment: I am not using any segue

Comment: Then best way is use UserDefault

Comment: @NishantBhindi that is bad coding style if you want to keep variable as long as your app exist then you have to use `UserDefault`

Comment: @GiriSugu how you are going to `ProfilePage`?

Comment: @Salman Ghumsani when I signed in I redirects to home page.From that page through side bar navigation I am going to profile page.When profile page loads I want to get information from API's.So I want to pass the token value which generated in SignInViewController to that API from ProfilePage viewcontroller

Comment: @GiriSugu in your case the from `SignInViewController` calls the `ProfilePage` implemented `sendToken` delegate method and the profile page doesn't exist in the navigation stack, If it exists then you have to get the exists instance of `ProfilePage`

Comment: How to you redirect to home page?

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani so I want to use navigation stack right? to receive the Token value from SignInViewController.

Comment: When I signed in I redirected to home page.

Comment: Yes, you can go!

Comment: Read the comment and answer I already mentioned the delegate problem!

Answer (score 0):

Just use "prepare for segue"

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if segue.identifier == "ProfileSegue" {
     if let vc = segue.destination as? ProfilePage {
       vc.token = self.token
    }
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
protocol sendTokenDelegate: class {
    func sendToken(login:String)
}
class SignInViewController: UIViewController  {
    weak var delegateToken:sendTokenDelegate?
    func loginAzure(email: String, password: String) {
        token = "abcdefgh"
        if self.delegateToken != nil{
         self.delegateToken?.sendToken(login: token)
        }
    }
}


class ProfilePage: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, sendTokenDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //get your instantiateViewController from storyboard
        let signInVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInViewControllerIdentifire") as! SignInViewController
        signInVC.delegateToken = self
    }
    func sendToken(login: String) {
        self.logInToken = login
        print("Login Token in Profile Page is \(login)")
    }
}
```

Comment: func sendToken(login: String) {
        self.logInToken = login
        print("Login Token in Profile Page is \(login)")
    } this is not calling

Comment: can you please show me your button method where your navigating Profile page to SignInViewController

Comment: @IBAction func SignInButton(_ sender: Any) { loginAzure() }  func loginAzure () { Alamofire.request("http://xxxxxxxx", method: .post, parameters: [ "email": mail,"password": pass], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
            response in let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.data!) JSONResponse[1] = String(describing: swiftyJsonVar["token"]) token = JSONResponse[1]  self.delegateToken?.sendToken(login: token)